# Apps Script: Return Array Item

Tags: google-apps-script

Well… I guess I better ask for some help on this one:

```
const name = “alain”;
const arr = ["alain@gmx.net", "james@gmx.net", "helen@gmx.net", "smith@gmx.net"];
```

All I wanna do is this: Search for the email-address starting with `“alain”` and return that email-address to me as a variable that I can use in other functions.

Any idea how this could be achieved?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const address = arr.find(element => element.startsWith(name))
```